# Updating mysql database?

Tags: mysql, hosting, database, share

I'm trying to install Wordpress for my website at the moment on my shared hosting.  There is currently a FrontPage site there.  When I go into the Plesk control panel and navigate to install Wordpress which the hosting company has put there, it says the mysql database is out of date and needs to be version 4.0.0 or higher.  How can I update it?  Do I need to remove the FrontPage site first or something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

removing the front page does not affect the mysql version installed. I would speak to the provider and ask them to confirm what the software is telling you. and if the mysql is less then 4 I would change providers as they do not keep their systems up to date!

Stuart

Comment: FYI

End of Product Lifecycle. 
Active development and support for MySQL database server versions 3.23, 4.0, and 4.1 has ended. However, for MySQL 4.0 and 4.1, there is still extended support available. For details, see http://www.mysql.com/company/legal/lifecycle/#calendar. According to the MySQL Lifecycle Policy (see http://www.mysql.com/company/legal/lifecycle/#policy), only Security and Severity Level 1 issues will still be fixed for MySQL 4.0 and 4.1. Please consider upgrading to a recent version (MySQL 5.0 or 5.1).